# Compose Function of 2 Arguments to Function of N Arguments

Tags: r, function, functional-programming

If I have a function like `union`, which takes the union of two sets, is there a concise way to write a function which takes the union of an arbitrary number of sets, i.e., `union_n(x, y, z, w) = union(x, union(y, union(z, w)))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Reduce`:

```
x <- 1:3
y <- 2:4
z <- 3:5
w <- 4:9
Reduce(union, list(x, y, z, w))
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

or as a function:

```
union_n <- function(...) Reduce(union, list(...))
union_n(x, y, z, w)
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

I ultimately solved this with recursion:

```
union_n <- function(x)
  if (length(x) == 1) x[[1]] else union(x[[1]], union_n(x[-1]))
```

However, I'm open to more elegant or computationally efficient solutions.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative without recursion might be this:

```
U2 = function(...) { unique(c(...)) }

x = 1:3
y = 3:5
z = seq(2,8,2)

U2(x,y,z)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 8
```